# [language(s)] --> [programming-languages] or [spoken-languages]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Request for comment: structured tag cleanups](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/request-for-comment-structured-tag-cleanups)

[[language]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language)
[[languages]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages)
[[programming-languages]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages)
[[spoken-languages]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoken-languages)

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate at all, but it is indeed highly related.

Comment: I prefer `natural-languages` over `spoken-languages`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer programming language.