# Why am I getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

Ok I wasn't asking a question but tried the link anyhow and it said

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See
>   http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

Here are the questions that I have asked in the past.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/112336/creating-a-blog-for-software-changes

[Should I update this code or continue with current design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93788/should-i-update-this-code-or-continue-with-current-design)

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/132878/how-to-sell-yourself-to-the-manager

My last question got closed, should I be banned just because of that?

Comment: I think you were banned because of the attitude you presented when your last question got closed. You went around flagging/commenting on many other questions to try and get them closed as well, and opened up a rant on meta about it.

Comment: @Rachel agree. I was just going to accept the answer but I will wait now. I would say there is a contribution of moderators in it. It can't be automatic because, otherwise all moderators would be banned as they put comments everywhere. But lets find out

Comment: duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi

Comment: I asked `No longer can ask question on Programmers:SE, what is the reason`. This was later modified. I knew it is a ban. My concern was, why would I be banned and by what logic?

Comment: It's worth repeating (from the comments on the answer) that this question ban is _fully automatic_. The attitude you present when your question gets closed has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I did not show any attitude. Two things happened to me and two questions posted here. If I am not worth programmers.SE, I do not need to be here.

Comment: Your questions look fine to me; but is @Rachel correct? Did you really go around flagging other questions trying to get them closed too?

Comment: @JimG. Yes about 2 or 3 in total. Out of which one was already flagged by another user. One thing I should mention, I am also banned on meta.stackexchange by asking [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109174/bad-question-should-not-show-up-at-the-top-of-search-results). That ban is still intact while here I can now post questions.

Comment: Good to see asking question got negative votes but the answer is +10 !!! so good answers can come from bad questions? does that still make the question bad ? What an idiotic system

Comment: @jimjim moderators here aren't the kindest souls. Most have attitudes, big time. Downvoting a normal question is also a sign of attitude. I am not an attitude guy by the way, I may disagree but on a valid point only.

Comment: @Noname : moderator or not, as soon as we attribute a problem to a person or group of people then nothing will improve, the problem is the system, never  people. Want improvement then change the system, people come and go but system determines how things are done.

Answer (score 10):

The [canonical answer to this is on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi), which is where the link in the notice takes you:

> An automatic filter is in place to ban questions from IP addresses or accounts with a history of extremely poor questions. To avoid bypassing the filter its internal rules are a secret, but it is partly based on downvotes cast by other members of the communities.
>
> Once you have posted too many bad quality questions, you will be banned from asking more, and see the error message. You can then still use the site, except for asking questions.

Looking at [your profile](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/30160/dave), you've asked 6 questions, only one of which has been upvoted, 4 of which were closed, and 3 of which were deleted. You've provided few answers, and only one of which was up-voted.

If you'd like to ask questions in the future, focus on helping others first by providing high-quality answers and taking [the feedback you've received on your past closures](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3029/8) to heart.  While the details of the low-quality ban are purposefully kept secret, creating a trend of high-quality answers generally will help towards getting it removed.

Comment: Let me correct it. I asked 3 question here (the ones list above), one was migrated from stack overflow and 2 on meta.programmers (I see them now in a different link, did not notice before), a total of 6. My real question were the above three. The rest were on other site. It would make more sense if I were banned here on meta rather than programmers.

Comment: Ummm I think all new users ask bad questions. I know I did. And if someone is banned for asking too many poor-quality questions, you definitely shouldn't encourage them to be answering questions. Instead, you should educate them on what makes a good question, perhaps by revising one of their existing questions.

Comment: @Dave Looking at your profile, only one question was migrated: the others were straight up closures. I can't get into the specifics of how the ban works, but the ban is automatic and it's a direct result of your activity here. The MSO post explains a little more.

Comment: @Rachel The ban is permanent, and revising questions will not help. It's the system specifically saying, "if you want to keep contributing here, [you need to do it in the form of answers.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)"

Comment: @MarkTrapp Out of curiosity, is a ban automatic or is it user-initiated?

Comment: @Rachel This particular ban is automatic based on question/answer history: I couldn't lift it even if I wanted to. The only way to have it lifted is to provide high-quality answers so the account's overall quality score improves.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Alright, I'm a bit surprised since his user profile doesn't seem that bad... if we automatically banned anyone that has a question closed with at least a -2, I'm sure we'd be banning more people. His P.SE account only has 3 questions posted to it, and only one is closed and has a negative score.

Comment: @Rachel Keep in mind as a regular user, you don't have access to the whole picture (for example, you don't see deleted questions listed on an account), even though those private things are contributing factors to the automatic ban.

Comment: @Rachel A number of questions are deleted, so you can't see them on his profile (Mark mentioned it in his answer)

Comment: @MarkTrapp Oh yeah, forgot about that :)

Comment: @MarkTrapp, the six question you refer to are on three sites, not on programmers:SE. I mentioned them in first comment. Can you give me just one of those deleted question so I see, it is for sure? I haven't used SE that much to my knowledge.

Comment: @Dave This isn't "Let's make a deal": I've already explained to you why the automatic ban kicked in, and that we can't get into the specifics. If you'd like to try and contest the ban, feel free to use the contact email at the bottom of every page, but bear in mind the chances of this being lifted without you improving your activity here [are low](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62373/give-better-explanations-when-accounts-are-blocked/62374#62374).

Comment: @MarkTrapp, I appreciate you answer. And I dont intend to open my account. Just wanted to know what really happened. I wanted to sent you `my other three` qustions but I can't see them anymore (they were available just an hour ago). Just a brief. I have 3 question here and 3 answers in total here. Appreciate you patience.

Comment: @Mark Trapp: +1 for 'This isn't Let's Make a Deal'.

Comment: @MarkTrapp, how can I post question again on Programmers? You said the ban is permanent?

Comment: @Dave Please re-read my answer, and the post linked in the message you received: they both explain what you need to do moving forward.

Comment: I re-read it and also read one of your comments `@Rachel The ban is permanent, and revising questions will not help`. I am not arguing. Commenting for sake of knowledge is not arguing. But I did not ask any question after that, but I am able to ask questions. What's the logic?