# Please unblock me

Tags: support, moderators, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why am I getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/why-am-i-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account)

Well I dont know whether to ask this in programmers meta is good or not, but please please unblock me, mods mailed me to reply, I replied to mods' reply on my blockage [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/message/319#319), but yet didnt get reply back from him. I got blocked on 9 Oct 2012 and its very hard time since then, please unblock me, I assure everyone that I will be more careful while asking questions next time.

Comment: I'll be honest - I don't see anything on your account that would warrant a block.

Comment: @JimG. That's because you can't see deleted posts.

Answer (score 7):

As ChrisF [already mentioned](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5396/25936) you were never suspended by a moderator. We send you a message on Oct 9 expressing concerns about your questions, but that was just a friendly warning.

The automatic question block, that we have absolutely no control over, kicked in at the same time. While the mod message did *not* trigger the question block, since the two events coincided I can understand why you thought the block was initiated by the moderators, and on behalf of the community I'd like to apologize for the confusion.

I've repeatedly asked Stack Exchange to let moderators know when the question block has kicked in, to avoid situations like these, but they've denied all my requests. I honestly feel like an idiot when I send a mod message explaining to the user what they can do to ask better questions in the future, only to find out that they can't ask questions because of the block. I would send a very different message if I knew the block was already in place (or I wouldn't send a message at all).

The question block is something only you can reverse. You should concentrate on giving great answers, and follow all the advice given in the Meta Stack Overflow question ChrisF linked to.

Answer (score 6):

Your account was never suspended by a moderator.

If you are getting the message:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account

then this is an automatic process which we cannot affect.

Please read [this Meta Stack Overflow question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) and it's answers to guide you on what you can do to get the ban lifted.