# Got a question ban with no recent deleted posts -- how to fix?

Tags: support, post-ban

I got banned from Programmers.SE. I have one question with a score of 0 and one answer with a score of -1. I remember having a past question that was deleted, but it does not show up in "Recent deleted questions", so I can't go back and fix it.

I would like to see the questions that were deleted, so I at least have a chance of fixing them.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/why-am-i-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two likely questions that contributed to the question ban were these two, both of which received a pretty significant net negative score:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/228891 - -5

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219843 - -4

You are also not blocked from answering questions, so contributing answers (along with [the other steps on this page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)) should help get over this block. Note that moderators can not lift it - the only way to get over this block is by contributing positively to the community.

Comment: I got un-banned (I think because of a high-scoring answer)

Comment: @Demetri thats quite likely (all positive contributions are taken into account when the system checks for a ban).  That means that you're also sitting on the edge of another one.  You should strive to continue to post high quality content both for your questions and answers to avoid another such ban.