# Why is my account blocked from asking new questions when I've asked just one question with 0 downvotes?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, post-ban

My [account](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/85118/geotarget) has been blocked from asking new questions.

Only 1 question asked (0 downvotes). Whats up? Why? Can I unblock this?

Comment: You are not shown your deleted questions, and we can't see them either.  They still count towards the question block, however.

Comment: question block also happens on a different level than just accounts, did you have another account that got blocked?

Comment: have you tried ["show removed posts" feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155999/show-removed-posts-in-reputation-history-by-default)? it's off by default and one can't see these

Comment: You have 3 deleted questions. Two were downvoted, closed and eventually deleted, and the third one you deleted yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/why-am-i-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does deleting a closed question remove a question ban?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7745/does-deleting-a-closed-question-remove-a-question-ban)