# Does deleting a closed question remove a question ban?

Tags: support, closed-questions, deleted-questions, post-ban

I asked a question recently which was closed as being too broad. I disagreed with the reasoning, but I understand the position that programmers.SE moderators took on it and I want to ask questions that are less opinion-based. My question is now... if I delete that question, will that remove my question block so I can ask a different question? Or do I need to simply wait it out? Not trying to game the system here, just wondering if deleting it is enough of a "good deed" to terminate the question ban.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/why-am-i-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this applies to all StackExchange sites, it's covered on Meta StackExchange in [this FAQ Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). This is the part that answers your question:

> **Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts!** As noted above,
>   down-votes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so
>   the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any
>   objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did
>   they fail to show any effort on your part? Poorly worded, titled,
>   formatted, and overly long or short? **Then fix them!**
>
> Note the emphasis on fixing. **Do not delete your posts.** As explained
>   above, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) do
>   still count towards the question ban. Deleting your posts does not
>   help to lift the ban. Only fixing does! Under some conditions you can
>   see a list of your own deleted questions and answers.
>
> If you are banned from asking questions, then writing a few quality
>   answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again. But
>   as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for
>   sure.

Comment: In this case, I don't believe the question is fixable, because the core of the question is what was seen as too broad. So I guess, if you can't fix it, the only thing to do is wait? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius Now that I've looked up the question you're referring to, I would agree that not much can be done to "fix" it. I'm honestly surprised that you got a question ban, considering you had two upvoted, non-closed questions before this one. But as far as I know your only options are waiting and/or writing some good answers instead.

Comment: @lxrec I was surprised by that too. I would think the algorithm needs more than 1/3 bad questions to kick in. But it's only for two days, so not the end of the world.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius 2/4, there's also [this one](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/263785/25936). That said, I don't disagree the q-ban feels a bit over-eager here.

Comment: @Yannis Ah, thanks for pointing that out. The ban makes more sense now. Perhaps there should be some way for a user to see how many of their questions have been deleted after the fact; there seems to be way no way of finding deleted questions, or a count of them, from my profile. (Clicking the Recently Deleted Questions doesn't show it.)

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius The question block is surprising to me, too...unfortunately, even as a mod, I can't do anything. But I don't know where you get that it's only 2 days. My understanding is that there is no way to tell how long this block will be in place, since it's all automatic and algorithmic. I do hope it is resolved, though, since you're contributions tend to be positive and you're willing to understand what it takes to make a high quality question here that's useful to you as well as others.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I appreciate the sentiment, thanks. Just fyi, when you try to post a new question, the help page includes this line: `It's been 1 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait 1 days before asking again.` That's where the 2 days is from.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius Did it actually stop you from asking another question today, or was it just asking nicely?

Comment: @ThomasOwens Don't quite remember when this was introduced, but q-blocks are more of a rate limit now (well, at least the first one you hit):  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited.

Comment: @lxrec It stops you with a "You've reached your question limit" at the top. Maybe a little overzealous, but I understand the purpose of it. No complaints here.

Comment: @Yannis this feature was introduced at SO in mid 2014: [Breaking down question blocks - let's talk about rate limits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236568/165773) and network wide in Nov 2014: [Rolling question rate limits are now network-wide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243460/165773)