# Getting unblocked from asking questions

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I don't really know how exactly that happened. I got a few questions that apparently weren't that great but now my account is not able to ask questions here.

The thing is that I really got something that does not fit to stack**overflow** and not to Code Review.

I already tried to contact *Programmers* but I didn't get an answer. The thing is that I can just create another account using one of my trash-mail accounts.

The help center says:

> "*The only way to end a posting block is to positively contribute to the site; automatic bans never expire or "time out".*"

but does not define "positive contribution". Since I don't know how much and in what matter I have to contribute I think I'm just going to create a new account, isn't that the only logical response?

My questions can't have been so stupid that I deserve to get blocked here imho - and after all I am maintaining my exchange accounts which means I am removing questions that appear to be off-topic or something like that.

It appears that I got automatically blocked and those blocks are set to be unlimitted - how stupid is that? I mean come on. This brings a user just closer to the point where he just creates another account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/why-am-i-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account)

Answer (score 3):

[Meta Stack Exchange has a good writeup about what to do when you are automatically blocked from creating new questions or new answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). You should first attempt to fix your posts, if you can. Some aren't salvageable, but others are. If you aren't sure, asking about your questions on Meta or [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) The block also only affects one type of post - if you're blocked from new questions, contributing good answers is one method to work toward having the block listed.

Creating a new account won't help either. As mentioned in the Meta Stack Exchange post, as of December 2010, it is at [a lower level than accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72180/clarify-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account-error/76167#comment-174366). Also consider that if successfully created, your accounts made to circumvent a suspension or block may also be removed.

Comment: for the sake of completeness, there seems to be [officially legitimate option](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285981/839601) to restart at slower rate: "If you opt to delete your account and then later return to the site, your ability to ask questions may be limited to one question per week until you have demonstrated an ability to ask useful questions."