# Why have I reached question limit? My questions were not downvoted

Tags: support, questions

I can't ask questions at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com anymore.

Why? I don't see my questions downvoted:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/45576/porton?tab=questions&sort=activity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/why-am-i-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account)

Answer (score 6):

You can't ask because you have a number of deleted, down-voted questions which are also taken into account when the system calculates whether you can post or not.

If you go to your profile and click the "[deleted recent questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/45576)" link you'll be able to see any of your most recent questions that have been deleted. Unfortunately, the most recent question was from December 2018 and is too old to appear in that list.

Deleting questions is a double edged sword, yes it removes them from your profile and restores the lost reputation but they still count against you and cannot be improved and potentially up-voted.

I suggest you concentrate on other activities like answering, suggesting useful edits, etc., as the ban will age away as the questions get older and drop out of consideration.